# How to send json Object in http post request in Java

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to send below code as Json array in post request , Here is my Json:

```
        *{
            "date": "2019-01-01",
            "source": {
                "type": "calendar"
            },
            "device": {
                "type": "mobile"
            }
        }*
    Here is my code
    
        
    
    **JSONArray array1 = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject obj3 = new JSONObject();
    
        obj.put("date","2019-01-01");
        obj2.put("type","calendar");
        obj3.put("type","mobile");
        array1.put(obj2.toString());
    
        obj.put("source",array1.toString());
        obj.put("device",array2.toString());**
```

Now i want to send this object in post request. How do i do that?

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().POST(obj)
```

here how can i send the "obj" in post request

Comment: Your code doesn't represent the json you post at the beginning. Also, are you using Java HttpRequest since Java 9 or an external library?

Answer (score 1):

Using MockMvc, as an example, will be like this:

```
[...]

ObjectMapper objectMapper;

MvcResult result = 
            mockMvc
                .perform(post(URL)
                .headers(headers)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(MY OBJECT)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andReturn();
```

I've used this example code in my tests project. I guess ObjectMapper will help you! :)